# Best practices for isolated lab setup

Tags: testing-environment

I am setting up a lab to do some testing.

Per policy, the lab must be separated by a jumphost.

This lab contains database and application servers that mirror the production environment.

I am about to install my development tools (Visual Studio) in my case in the lab so they can talk to the application and database servers there.

It is somewhat annoying to have to use a remote session to get to Visual Studio in my case and deal with the small lag time etc.

I don't really have an option right?  I could install visual studio on my laptop, copy code over and run it.  But then when I need to step through code to do debugging I cannot really do that without visual studio installed in the isolated lab...

How do you have your environment set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally for me, I find it easiest to run tests off of my local machine. I integrate my testing suite with the nightly builds, and they are run at the end of the build for my testing environment. So when I arrive in the morning I can take a look at the results sheet, and get people on the issues right away. ***Visual studio is tied by a user***, and cannot be installed machine to machine. Below is some information I found on using your license with multiple computers from the following stack overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676042/visual-studio-licensing-per-user-or-per-machine.

*Visual Studio is licensed per user. You can have one installation on your laptop and another on your desktop as long as they are both used by you only (or any other user has a license). Here's  Microsoft's whitepaper on licensing.*

Comment: Thanks for the information, but what do you do if you are writing an application that talks to an application or database server and that application or database server is isolated?  Are you saying after you commit the code it runs against the test environment?  Doesn't that make developing harder as that application server would be in the test environment isolated from you?  The licensing info is interesting and applies to many people but in my scenario we have all you can eat visual studio licenses.

Comment: In my case I am referring specifically to a build being completed for stage (Test) environment, then my test suite runs after that completed build. So if the application/database is isolated, what exactly do you mean by this? you are only able to access it from one location? it would help to know what you are testing (only explain at a high level)

Answer (score 0):

There are not enough details in the question, but since you mentioned the possibility to remote access into the lab than visual studio can be used for remote debugging there.